# Convert string to two byte hex unicode in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, utf-8, ucs2

I'm translating messages using Bing Translator and sending the results via SMS text message. The resulting strings often contain non-English characters, e.g. Korean, Japanese, Greek.

I am using the Clickatell SMS Gateway and according to the Clickatell spec here: http://www.clickatell.com/downloads/http/Clickatell_HTTP.pdf
...I think I should encode my strings in two-byte Unicode, hex-encoded.

For example, the Greek characters:

> ΩΨΘ

After conversion should become:

> 03A903A80398

Which is then added to the querystring in my HTTP get request.

**My issue however is finding the syntax to to this succinctly in my Ruby on Rails app.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like fun ones like these. :)  Try this:

```
input.codepoints.map { |c| "%04X" % c }.join
```

What I see:

```
[1] pry(main)> x = "\u03A9\u03A8\u0398"
=> "ΩΨΘ"
[2] pry(main)> x.codepoints.map { |c| "%04X" % c }.join
=> "03A903A80398"
```

Comment: Didn't know about `codepoints`, nice!  And the `%04X` is obvious now, duh.  Updated answer...

Comment: Thanks guys! Though if in rails console I do `x = 'ΩΨΘ'` then `x.codepoints.map { |c| "%04X" % c }.join` I get `"212603A80398"` not `"03A903A80398"`?

Comment: You must have a [Unicode Ohm sign (2126)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2126/index.htm) there, instead of the [Omega (03A9)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a9/index.htm) you're thinking you have.  The result is correct.

Comment: You're right. Clickatell documentation has this wrong, copying and pasting from there creates this confusing result, will let them know.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to split -- use each_char instead to iterate.
Call map directly on each_char (or collect) and use capital "X" instead of lower "x" instead of upcase

```
input.each_char.map{|c| "%04X" % c.ord}.join
```

Comment: Thanks! Though if in rails console I do `input = 'ΩΨΘ'` then `input.each_char.map{|c| "%04X" % c.ord}.join` I get `"212603A80398"` not `"03A903A80398"`?

Comment: Strange, I get "03A903A80398" in my console.  I'm using Ruby 2.0